# Family of unary partial computable functions having total computable extension is computable.

Tags: computability, partial-functions

I have to prove:

> Family of unary partial computable functions having
> total computable extension is computable.

But it is not so obvious for me.

Here i provide some definitions:

> If the function $h$ is obtained from the computable functions $f$ and $g$ and they are defined everywhere, then $h$ is a total function.

> A function $g$ is called an extension of the function $f$ (partial function) if $Dom (f) ⊆ Dom (g)$ and $g (x) = f (x)$ for any $x ∈ Dom (f)$.
> Where $Dom (f)$ is the scope of function $f$.

Comment: It's hard to prove because it's false.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Can you explain why is it false?